# Are there any systems for logging or keeping track of which type of bugs you encounter as you develop?

Tags: debugging, build, bug-tracking

I'm not looking for bug tracking, per se.  But more like a build tool: as a developer, it would be awesome if every time I compiled or tried to run code, I could redirect debugging output and record the bugs I most commonly introduce, how long they take to resolve, etc.

Is there anything like this out there?

Comment: yes loads, we use [jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i know that [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/) has something that you can hit a webservice of theirs with specific information to log the bug. You might be able to add some code to only hit this service for debugging.

We use them for our bug tracking and its an awesome site

Comment: Thanks, looks like that's the best of what's around.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem here is thinking that the "mistakes" or "bugs" you make while developing are somehow "abnormal".  They are not. They are part of "investigating the fix to the problem". :-)

Mistakes in coding are not "Bugs" until they get checked into the master sources.  If you find and fix them as part of your "investigation" on how to fix the particular problem assigned to you, that's just called ... "being a programmer".

Building and testing your "personal" copy of the code before checking it in is how you avoid introducing "bugs" into the project. :-)

Comment: Sure, I don't mean that bugs are bad--I just mean that I'd like to see what sorts of mistakes I most commonly make, how long they take to resolve, etc.  I'm more looking for a tool to support reflective programming =)